# How to set GIF to run smoothly while code is executing behind?

Tags: android, performance, gif

I have an Activity which needs to display a GIF while some heavy stuff is happening behind. I'm not refering to spash screens. The Gif is in the same layout as other views.

Usecase: 1. Activity Starts and I set view visibility, where the GIF stands, to TRUE 2. Forground service starts and some requests (async) to the server are made to fetch content (GIF blocks here and I don't know why) 3. After the service finishes the network jobs, a callback is called and the view with the gif is set to GONE.

If I replace the gif with a ProgressBar, the freezing doesn't happen. It spinns until I set it to GONE.

I use Glide to display the gif.
Here is the activity_base.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/inject_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!--    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView-->
<!--        android:visibility="gone"-->
<!--        android:id="@+id/view_download_progress"-->
<!--        android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
<!--        android:background="@color/white"-->
<!--        android:src="@drawable/service_download_content"/>-->

    <ProgressBar
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/view_download_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@color/white"/>

<!--    <ImageView-->
<!--        android:visibility="gone"-->
<!--        android:id="@+id/view_download_progress"-->
<!--        android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
<!--        android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
<!--        android:background="@color/white" />-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

UPDATE:
This is how I toggle the visibility

```
        ImageView downloadProgress = findViewById(R.id.view_download_progress);
        if (value) {
            Glide.with(getContext()).asGif().load(R.drawable.test).into(downloadProgress);
            downloadProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            downloadProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

UPDATE2:
The commented method does some heavy SQLite work after the retrofit callback is called inside the job that is executed inside the service. The gif isn't freezing if I do this.

```
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<ObjectsSchema>, response: Response<ObjectsSchema>) {
                        val cmsContent = response.body() as ObjectsSchema
//                        handleContent(cmsContent)
                        notifyOnDownloadSucceded()
                    }
```

Comment: difficult not seeing the code, but sounds like glide and your service are using the same thread. Maybe a setting in okhttp?

Comment: @IgnacioTomasCrespo I've edited the question. The project is quite big. Please tell me if you need to see something specific.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use **Glide** to load GIF. I've built a project on GitHub that is using it to load GIF in AlertDialog.

[android-dialog](https://github.com/jhonatansabadi/android-dialog)

```
Glide.with(activity)
            .load(imageUrl)
            .into(customView.imageDialog)
```

Answer (score 0):

I handled the problem with coroutine.

```
    fun executeAsync() {
        mStlClubApi.downloadCmsBulkData(mUrl, mQuery)
                .enqueue(object: Callback<ObjectsSchema> {
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<ObjectsSchema>, t: Throwable) {
                        notifyOnDownloadFailed()
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(call: Call<ObjectsSchema>, response: Response<ObjectsSchema>) {
                        val cmsContent = response.body() as ObjectsSchema

                        CoroutineScope(IO).launch {
                            asyncHandleAndNotify(cmsContent)
                        }
                    }
                })
    }

    private suspend fun asyncHandleAndNotify(cmsContent: ObjectsSchema) {
        handleContent(cmsContent)
        notifyOnDownloadSucceded()
    }
    abstract suspend fun handleContent(cmsContent: ObjectsSchema)
```

However, I still don't know why is it blocking the GIF if the jobs are executing in the context of a Foreground service, but I think it's a subject for another question and deep debug.